# Exchange Server 2019 can't send email on port 25

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2022, exchange-server

I have setup a windows server 2022 with Exchange 2019 and am unable to send out email because outgoing port 25 is blocked.

Vultr.com says they have removed the default SMTP block from my barebones server. They claim the port is open both inbound and outbound. Also Vultr firewall is unavailable for barebones servers.

I have done the following:

1. Stopped the firewall (Windows Defender) completely [[Image]](https://mail.thedocs.md/img/firewall.jpg)
2. Uninstalled virus protection
3. Updated the LAN driver to the latest Intel driver
4. Checked the OS several different ways for corruption

None of that has mattered.

NMAP shows that port 25 is open on the new server from our office, but closed when I go from the new server to our Office Exchange Server.

Further, telnet testing shows I can connect to the new server from our office but I can connect from the new server to our Office Exchange Server on port 25 nor to portquiz.net.

Can you think of any way or reason that Windows Server 2022 or Exchange Server could be blocking port 25? Or any other testing I could do?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do other ports work to portquiz.net?

Comment: Yea every other port I have tried goes right into telenet with telnet portquiz.net #

Comment: then Vultr.com is mistaken or lying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jaromanda X was correct, Vultr was blocking the port.  It took them several weeks for them to figure out why.